# Как создать object{Переменный : значение} ? Object.fromEntries() не работает

Tags: javascript, firebase

Я новичок в JavaScript. Развертываю Firebase Function.
Мой код выглядит так:

```
const entries = new Map([
    ['foo', 'bar'],
    ['baz', 42]
]);

const obj = Object.fromEntries(entries);
console.log(obj);
```

Но это выдает такую ошибку:

```
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
at commonRatingsDoc.get.then.queryResult (/srv/index.js:66:38)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

Но в тоже время `Object.entries()` работает нормально.

Все это мне нужно что бы я смог использовать метод `Firestore.update()`
Но для этого в метод `update()` нужно передать `{key: value}` объект(я точно не уверен называется ли это объектом)

То есть это должно выглядит как то так `mFirestore.update({ key : value })`
Но дело в том, что `key` и есть как бы ключь, а не переменный. Я не понимаю почему это так работает.

У меня `key` может меняться, я не знаю как этого достичь.

Comment: Не понятно, в каком контексте и что именно не работает? Вы принцип показали, он работает, а где ваш код, который не работает?

Comment: @Leonid не работает Object.fromEntries(entries); Пишет что функция fromEntries() не существует.